# multipart data request to controller

Tags: c#, controller, multipartform-data

I have controller that creates file on filesystem, file attached in request. During development I tested my controller work via fiddler request composer where upload file to request option was provided.How can I test my controller work using unit testing? I mean call my controller something like this

```
[TestClass]
public class DocumentsControllerTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void DocumentsTest()
    {
       var documentsController = new DocumentsController();
       documentsController.post(12323, "somedata"); <--here in params i send some data
    }
}
```

in post method params I send some additional data(info about document owner).How to send file in this code(as I did via fiddler)?

Comment: Please, rephrase you question until it is readable.

Answer (score 0):

You have to mock it. You can use Moq for example. There is a good [article about it](http://blog.csainty.com/2009/01/aspnet-mvc-unit-test-file-upload-with.html)